# How to place SliverToBoxAdapter inside of a Column?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, customscrollview

I am struggling with placing SliverToBoxAdapter inside of a Column. I need to keep widgets stuck in column, not scrolling them. I do need any CustomScrollView and scrolling property obtained by slivers.

The error which appears is:

> A RenderFlex expected a child of type RenderBox but received a child
> of type RenderSliverToBoxAdapter. RenderObjects expect specific types
> of children because they coordinate with their children during layout
> and paint. For example, a RenderSliver cannot be the child of a
> RenderBox because a RenderSliver does not understand the RenderBox
> layout protocol.

Comment: Can you include code-snippet ? & what are you trying to archive

Comment: you cannot place `SliverToBoxAdapter` inside `Column`, you can use it only where sliver is required (for example inside `CustomScrollView`)

Answer (score 1):

You can not place SliverToBoxAdapter inside a Column or Row widget. You need to put it inside CustomScrollView view, which is give you layout like Column as well.  SliverToBoxAdapter is a sliver which you only put inside CustomScrollView.
[enter link description here](https://www.dbestech.com/tutorials/flutter-customscrollview-and-slivers)

Here's an example

```
CustomScrollView(
            reverse: true,
            controller: controller.myscrollController,
            slivers: [

          SliverPadding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 0.w,
              horizontal: 0.w,
            ),
            sliver: SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (content, index) {
                    var item = controller.state.msgcontentList[index];
                    if(controller.token==item.token){
                      return ChatRightItem(item);
                    }
                    return ChatLeftItem(item);
                  },
                  childCount: controller.state.msgcontentList.length,
                )
            ),
          ),
              SliverPadding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.w, horizontal: 0.w),
                  sliver:SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child:controller.state.isloading.value?Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,child: new Text('loading...'),):Container(),
                  )
              ),
        ])
```

The above code should give you an idea about the layout of CustomScrollView and SliverToBoxAdaptor